# How can I set this up to run two onedit functions in the same sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

all

If you put the two together they don't work
  What is the right code to work together
Note that the first to arrange automatic
The second is to set the date if you put only one works, but if you add the other all stops working

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 13;
  var tableRange = "A2:Y";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
  }
}


{
function onEdit(e) {
var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var sheets = [];
var ind = [2].indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
  var stampCols = [13]


if(sheets.indexOf(sh.getName()) ==-1 || ind == -1) return;
sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, stampCols[ind]).setValue(typeof e.value == 'object' ? null : new Date )


}
}
```

sheet test
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mFqHdeF6l25XeyIOXwcdKqnYC27BrvZd1MaskHNAdJc

Answer (score 1):

```
function onEdit(e){

 onEdit1(e);

  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 13;
  var tableRange = "A2:Y";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );


  onEdit2(e);

var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var sheets = [];
var ind = [13].indexOf(e.range.columnStart);
  var stampCols = [2]

if(sheets.indexOf(sh.getName()) ==-1 || ind == -1) return;
sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, stampCols[ind]).setValue(typeof e.value == 'object' ? null : new Date )


}
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mFqHdeF6l25XeyIOXwcdKqnYC27BrvZd1MaskHNAdJc/edit#gid=1945346364

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, functions names should be unique on each Google Apps Script project. Let say that you want to follow the easier path, to do this:

1. Change the functions names, to something like `onEdit1` and `onEdit2`
2. Add an `onEdit` function that will call the previous renamed functions

   ```
   function onEdit(e){
     onEdit1(e);
     onEdit2(e);
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you for answer But i try but not working or i make mistake can you help me more type full code !

Comment: @Ibrahimkamal Please edit your question to show your progress including the steps you followed to test the code and the [execution transcript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#execution_transcript).